# Converting ESRI SHP to MapInfo TAB via Python QGIS 2.18.1

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am attempting to convert a few files from ESRI Shapefiles to MapInfo Tab via python. As I understand, the 'gdalogr:convertformat' processing algorithm can be used for this. My code looks something like this at the moment...

```
def convert_layer(layer,filetype, save_location):
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()
    print "Converting", layer, "to Mapinfo TAB..."
    processing.tools.general.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat',layer, filetype, "", save_location)

convert_layer("path/to/layer.shp", 5, "path/to/tab")
```

When I run this, QGIS reports that the conversion was successful, however no files are placed in the output folder.

To make matters more confusing, this same process seems to work fine in QGIS 2.14.

Has something changed between 2.14 and 2.18?

Comment: Are you running this in the Python Console or as a standalone script?

Comment: I am running all code in the QGIS console

Answer (score 3):

If you're running your code in the **Python Console** in QGIS, you can shorten your code to:

```
import processing
def convert_layer(layer, filetype, save_location):
    print "Converting", layer, "to Mapinfo TAB..."
    processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat', layer, filetype, "", save_location)

convert_layer("path/to/layer", 5, "path/to/tab")
```

---

I tested the following code in QGIS 2.18.2 for Windows 7 64-bit and received a `.tab` file as output:

```
convert_layer("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/point_example.shp", 5, "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/output")
```

See if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you.

It would appear as though 2.18.1 is bugged. Myself and a colleague both tried your code and got no error messages but no TAB file outputs.

On my 2.14 install, your code worked perfectly.

Looks as though the solution is either to downgrade to 2.14 or upgrade to 2.18.2!

Comment: @JamieTasker - Most welcome! Hmm, in your `/user/.qgis2/python/plugins` directory, is there a folder named "processing"? If so, try removing this from the directory, load QGIS 2.18 and attempt the code again.

Comment: Still no dice I'm afraid... interestingly I just tried to downgrade a PC to 2.14.10 and the problem still happens. 

It's bizarre that only my 2.14.4 install seems to function correctly...

Comment: @JamieTasker - Bizarre indeed, perhaps try 2.18.2?